# How to change product categories URL structure in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to delete this text "product-category" before my product category in WordPress. I am using Woocommerce and OceanWP theme. See the attached picture below.I want this product  URL to be [www.domain.com/laptop](http://www.domain.com/laptop)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roYn6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please read woocommerce documentation article first https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/

You can change this step by:

1. you can change the permalinks in Settings > permalink > optional >
   Product category base= ./ (type ./ in Product category base).
2. Be sure that you don’t have any page, post or attachment with the
   the same name (slug) as the category page or they will collide and the
   code won’t work.
3. Install and activate the plugin below: The link is
   (https://timersys.com/remove-product-category-slug-woocommerce/)